# richfaces with jboss 5.1 - deploy-> ClassNotFoundException context.spi.context

Tags: jsf, jboss, richfaces

I try to create a JSF app with richfaces but I get a ClassNotFoundException as soon as I deploy the application on JBoss 5.1 (Java 1.6) (I cannot switch another JBoss version)

I defined the dependencies in the pom as follows:

```
   <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${org.richfaces.bom.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

...

```
<properties>
    <org.richfaces.bom.version>4.1.0.Final</org.richfaces.bom.version>       
</properties>
```

Any idea?
D3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jboss 5.1 supports JSF 1.2 and not JSF 2.x. Rich Faces 4.x is built to work on JSF 2.x

You are using Jboss 5.1, but defining the dependencies as Rich Faces 4.x.

Since you are telling that you cannot switch to another Jboss version(I assume higher versions), you must think of coming down to RichFaces 3.x